# java.lang.ClassCastException in context of generics

Tags: java, generics, casting

I'm currently working on generics in Java. So far, I tried to rebuild an ArrayList class called "Liste" (in German) and then I tried to implement generics, so my list can hold different objects, but also provide type-safety.

In my implementation, a `ClassCastException` is thrown when I try to cast my `Object` array to an `U` (in this case `Car`) array. The only thing I don't understand, is the fact that the code compiles when I'm not giving the specific bound (`U extends Car`). If I remove the bound, the code compiles and everything works fine.

```
public class CarListe<U extends Car> { // doesn't work with bound Car
    private U[] array;
    private int capacity;

    public CarListe(int capacity) {
        this.array = (U[]) new Object[capacity]; // the error ocurs in this line 
    }
}
```

Now the instantiation of a CarListe object

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        CarListe<Car> pkwCarListe = new CarListe<Car>(100);
        

    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Comment: `<U extends Car>` at runtime is erased to `Car` type which causes `(U[]) new Object[capacity]` to be compiled as `(Car[]) new Object[capacity]` which is causing the problem. Maybe instead of `CarListe<U extends Car>` create list for all kind of objects like `Liste<U>{...}` and later crate class with more *specific* content like `class CarListe<U extends Car> extends Liste<U>{ /*add constructors, etc*/}`.

Comment: I extended my CarList with my "normal" List (public class CarListe<U extends Car> extends Liste<U>) and it works. Thanks alot